# Error while updating the DataBase with Code First in Entity FrameWork

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am new in MVC4.0. I created a sample Internet application. I added a class

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
 }
```

Now, I want to add a new column called MiddleName in the User Table.

I have already add the property like below.

```
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

I have enabled the Migration in the project.

Now, I want to update the Database with this new column (MiddleName).

I tried below syntax in the Package Manager Console

```
PM> Update-Database
```

This giving me following error...

```
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : error 0005: The 'Namespace' attribute is invalid - The value 'MvcApplication14._5' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm:TNamespaceName' - The Pattern constraint failed.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModelOption, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, ItemCollection itemCollection, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.XDocumentExtensions.GetStorageMappingItemCollection(XDocument model, DbProviderInfo& providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : error 0005: The 'Namespace' attribute is invalid - The value 'MvcApplication14._5' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm:TNamespaceName' - The Pattern constraint failed.
```

Comment: Do you get same error when use `Update-Database -Verbose`?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi : I got the above error in Package Manager Console. Please check.

Comment: what version of entity framework you are using?the error message is not clear?!The 'Namespace' attribute is invalid

Comment: While creating the Sample application in MVC4, it gives Entity FrameWork Dll By Default i.e. 5.0.0.0

Comment: @abcdefghi yes I know, I mean Did you use `Update-Database` with `Verbose` parameter?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi : Can you please show the Step by Step information on how to update the Database using Code First in Entity FrameWork 5 and MVC4 ?

Answer (score 0):

first you should Enable Migration using this command in Package Manager Console:

```
Enable-Migrations
```

This command add a Migrations folder to your project,
after that you change your Model for example adding this property to your Model :

```
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

then you can update using this command :

```
Update-Database -Verbose
```

> We’ll specify the **–Verbose** flag so that we can see the SQL being run
>   against the database.

Answer (score 0):

It won't like the dot-underscore in your namespace `MvcApplication14._5`.  Remove the dot or underscore and it should work.